# Изменение заднего фона ячеек QTableWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Пишу приложение на python3.9 используя PyQt5 в котором фигурирует QTableWidget, в качестве улучшения внешнего вида приложения хотел изменить задний фон ячеек в таблице, чтобы они образовывали единый эллипс подобно тому, как они изображены на скриншоте:
[image: Ожидание]

Но столкнулся с проблемой: перелопатив половину форумов по PyQt лучшего решения чем это, не нашёл:
[image: Реальность]
Хотелось бы понять возможно ли добиться желаемого результата

В качестве stylesheet для QTableWidget использую следующее

```
    QTableWidget {
            background-color: rgba(92,92,92,1);
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid rbga(102,102,102,1);
    }

    QTableWidget::item {
            color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
            margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
            border-radius: 9px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
    }

    QTableWidget::item:selected {
        background-color: black;
        color: rgba(235,235,235,1);
    }
    QHeaderView{
        background-color: rgba(102,102,102,1);
    }
    QHeaderView::section {
        color: rgba(235,235,235,1);
            background-color: rgba(102,102,102,1);
            font-size: 12px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    QHeaderView::section:horizontal {
            border-top: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
    }

    QHeaderView::section:vertical {
        border-top: 0px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
    }
    QTableCornerButton::section {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(52,52,52,1);
        background-color: rgb(102,102,102);
    }
```

Уже приходили идеи накладывать задние фоны соседних ячеек друг на друга, но у ячейки в pyqt есть границы за которые её стиль не может заходить.